# why does ":type null" differs in Frege from Haskell?

Tags: haskell, frege

In Haskell :

```
ghci> :type null
null :: [a] -> Bool
```

In Frege :

```
frege> :type null
Empty α => α β -> Bool
```

How do I interpret this answer and why is there a difference?

(example from real-world haskell as adapted in real-world frege git repo)

Comment: Well frege != Haskell. It differs because they're different languages. It appears that Frege simply has a typeclass for things which know how to check if they're empty, it's more polymorphic than Haskells.

Comment: That was quick!
It would be helpful to hear about the rationale behind doing it differently. Since it is the more general - arguably cleaner - solution?

Comment: Yes, type inference can be interesting with code that's "too" generic. you can get something similar in Haskell with the classy-prelude package.

Comment: jozefg: I'd suggest making that an answer.

Comment: Also, if it was decided to add an `Empty` typeclass to the Haskell standard library, the Frege type for `null` would make sense, but changing the type of `null` would break existing code and that's something Haskell tries to avoid the benefit is quite significant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `String` is not `[Char]` in Frege, some (maybe half-hearted) attempts have been made to nevertheless guarantee a certain level of compatibility behind the scenes:

1. Type class `Empty` makes testing for the empty value (`null`) possible (should probably be a subclass of Monoid, though)
2. Type class `ListLike` gives you `head` and `tail` and `(++)`
3. Type class `ListSource` is for types that can be viewed as Lists (via operation `toList`). Currently, String, Maybe and arrays. Note that list comprehension not only allows `[a]`, but instances of `ListSource` on the right hand side of generators.

Both lists and strings are instances of the above classes and this way certain basic functions do work on both lists and strings, just like in Haskell, though the type of those functions is a bit more general in Frege.

Bottom line: As long as you use simple functions like `null`, `(++)`, `head`, `tail` and list comprehension you may not even notice that strings are not lists in Frege.